# Doctrine on linux: unable to connect to sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework, doctrine

I am trying to run a **zend + doctrine web application from a Debian 9 host, using php 5.6**

I've the need to **connect to a sql server** that is on different host (it's a windows machine, obviously)

I tested connection using *isql* command line and **I am correctly able to login and to operate** in the desired db

The problem is that **the webabb do not return me any error but simply fails to login** (i am not the developer of this webapp).

Configuration follows:

### odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTds]
Description = MS SQL database access with Free TDS
Driver      = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount  = 1
Trace       = Yes
TraceFile   = /tmp/odbcinst.log
```

### freetds.ini

*host ip is exact, I removed when pasting here*

```
[flower1]
 host = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 port = 1433
 tds version = 7.3
```

### odbc.ini

```
[test_flower1]
Description=Test for MSSQL Server on flower1
Driver=FreeTds
Database=test_flower1
ServerName=flower1
TDS_Version=7.3
```

### application.ini

```
;; Database
doctrine.dsn = "odbc:Driver={Sql_server};Server=flower1;Database=test_flower1;Uid=<redacted but correct>;Pwd=<redacted but correct>;"
```

How can I debug the source of the problem?

I've not previously experience with zend/doctrine

Comment: did you use zf1 or zf2?

Comment: @KoKsPfLaNzE: how can I see it? It's not mine the php code.

Comment: is there a composer.json file, in the root directory of the application, if yes please post it.
if not could you post the public/index.php file.

Comment: @KoKsPfLaNzE since he's showing us the "application.ini", I think he's using ZF1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to this

```
doctrine.dsn = "odbc:Driver={Sql_server};Server=flower1;Database=test_flower1;Uid=<redacted but correct>;Pwd=<redacted but correct>;"
```

I solved *simply adding the port !*

```
doctrine.dsn = "odbc:Driver={Sql_server};Server=flower1;Port=1433;Database=test_flower1;Uid=<redacted but correct>;Pwd=<redacted but correct>;"
```